# Adding tooltips to a Density Plot in React and D3.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, visualization

I'm trying to build a Density Plot using React and D3.js.

I would like the user to be able to hover on any part of the graph and see a tooltip displaying additional info on that specific point, but I'm not sure how I would add tooltips to the path element. I couldn't find any relevant examples. Has somebody worked on something similar?

Code: https://playcode.io/1640953

[image]

```
import {useMemo, useRef } from "react";
import * as d3 from "d3";

import  AxisBottom  from "./axisBottom";
import  AxisLeft  from "./axisTop";
import importedData from "./data"

const MARGIN = { top: 50, right: 30, bottom: 50, left: 50 };


export const DensityChart = ({ width = 700, height = 400}) => {
  const boundsWidth = width - MARGIN.right - MARGIN.left;
  const boundsHeight = height - MARGIN.top - MARGIN.bottom;

  const refs = useRef({
    dataMin: Math.min(...importedData),
    dataMax: Math.max(...importedData),
    domain: [Math.min(...importedData), Math.max(...importedData)]
  })

  const xScale = useMemo(() => {
    try {
      const result = d3.scaleLinear().domain([refs.current.dataMin, refs.current.dataMax]).range([10, boundsWidth - 10]);
      return result
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error creating xScale:", error);
      return d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 1]).range([10, boundsWidth - 10]);
    }
  }, [importedData, width]);

    // Compute kernel density estimation
    const density = useMemo(() => {
      const kde = kernelDensityEstimator(kernelEpanechnikov(7), xScale.ticks(40));
      return kde(importedData);
    }, [xScale, importedData]);

  const yScale = useMemo(() => {
    try {
      const max = Math.max(...density.map((d) => d[1]));
      const result = d3.scaleLinear().range([boundsHeight, 0]).domain([0, max])
      return result;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error creating yScale:", error);
      return
    }
  }, [importedData, height, density]);

  const path = useMemo(() => {
    try {
      const lineGenerator = d3.line().x((d) => {
       return xScale(d[0])
      })
      .y((d) => {
        return yScale(d[1])
      })
      .curve(d3.curveBasis);
      return lineGenerator(density);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error creating path:", error);
      return "";
    }
  }, [density, xScale, yScale]);


  return (
    <section>
    <svg height="500" width="700">
      <g
        width={boundsWidth}
        height={boundsHeight}
        transform={`translate(${[MARGIN.left, MARGIN.top].join(",")})`}
      >
       
        <path
          d={path}
          fill="blue"
          opacity={0.4}
          stroke="black"
          strokeWidth={1}
          strokeLinejoin="round"
        />
        <g transform={`translate(0, ${boundsHeight})`}>
          <AxisLeft yScale={yScale} pixelsPerTick={40} />
        </g>
        <g transform={`translate(0, ${boundsHeight})`}>
          <AxisBottom xScale={xScale} pixelsPerTick={40} />
        </g>

      </g>
    </svg>
    </section>
  );
}

export default DensityChart;

// Function to compute density
function kernelDensityEstimator(kernel, X) {
  return function(V) {
    return X.map(function(x) {
      return [x, d3.mean(V, function(v) { return kernel(x - +v )})];
    });
  };
}
function kernelEpanechnikov(bandwidth) {
  return function(v) {
    const result = Math.abs(v /= bandwidth) <= 1 ? 0.75 * (1 - v * v) / bandwidth : 0;
    return result
  };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Realistically your problem does not really have anything to do with d3. It can be resolved with normal javascript. SVG path still respect pointer events normally (as long as they have fill color or pointer event explicitly defined)

For instance using css to make path sections change color:

```css
path {
    fill:blue;
    stroke:black;
}
path:hover{
    fill:red;
    stroke:blue;
}
```

```html
<svg width="640" height="480" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <g>
  <title>Layer 1</title>
  <path id="svg_3" d="m200,114l-114,95l26,97l99,20c0,0 19,-67 19,-68c0,-1 -1,-5 4,-8c5,-3 39,-10 40,-10c1,0 13,-2 14,-9c1,-7 -4,-36 -8,-40c-4,-4 -23,-15 -27,-17c-4,-2 -24,-16 -24,-23c0,-7 -1,-15 -1,-21c0,-6 -6,-19 -7,-19c-1,0 -21,3 -21,3z" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="none"/>
  <path id="svg_4" d="m244,101c0,0 14,55 16,56c2,1 22,11 24,13c2,2 23,17 24,18c1,1 1,28 -1,31c-2,3 -3,25 -9,30c-6,5 -32,14 -35,14c-3,0 -8,5 -10,8c-2,3 -10,37 -10,37c0,0 7,10 16,15c9,5 53,12 59,12c6,0 30,0 40,-8c10,-8 34,-7 35,-31c1,-24 1,-48 1,-65c0,-17 -13,-61 -15,-66c-2,-5 -21,-21 -21,-23c0,-2 34,-20 44,-15c10,5 29,24 33,28c4,4 10,20 16,5c6,-15 28,-31 -1,-46c-29,-15 -25,-24 -55,-25c-30,-1 -42,-5 -53,-5c-11,0 -46,-2 -52,1c-6,3 -46,16 -46,16z" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="none"/>
  <path id="svg_5" d="m428,180c0,0 -3,52 -4,53c-1,1 -2,27 -2,31c0,4 -8,29 -11,34c-3,5 -15,36 -21,38c-6,2 -77,18 -81,18c-4,0 -68,0 -68,7c0,7 -1,18 8,23c9,5 23,9 45,14c22,5 97,12 111,6c14,-6 44,-20 55,-30c11,-10 28,-28 37,-42c9,-14 14,-15 23,-40c9,-25 16,-109 12,-114c-4,-5 -32,-12 -45,-9c-13,3 -59,11 -59,11z" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="none"/>
 </g>
</svg>
```

You can add javascript events the same way:

```js
Array
  .from(document.querySelectorAll("path"))
  .forEach((el) => {
    el.onmouseover = () => console.log("Mouse Over " + el.id);
  })
```

```css
path {
    fill:blue;
    stroke:black;
}
```

```html
<svg width="640" height="480" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <g>
  <path id="svg_3" d="m200,114l-114,95l26,97l99,20c0,0 19,-67 19,-68c0,-1 -1,-5 4,-8c5,-3 39,-10 40,-10c1,0 13,-2 14,-9c1,-7 -4,-36 -8,-40c-4,-4 -23,-15 -27,-17c-4,-2 -24,-16 -24,-23c0,-7 -1,-15 -1,-21c0,-6 -6,-19 -7,-19c-1,0 -21,3 -21,3z" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="none"/>
  <path id="svg_4" d="m244,101c0,0 14,55 16,56c2,1 22,11 24,13c2,2 23,17 24,18c1,1 1,28 -1,31c-2,3 -3,25 -9,30c-6,5 -32,14 -35,14c-3,0 -8,5 -10,8c-2,3 -10,37 -10,37c0,0 7,10 16,15c9,5 53,12 59,12c6,0 30,0 40,-8c10,-8 34,-7 35,-31c1,-24 1,-48 1,-65c0,-17 -13,-61 -15,-66c-2,-5 -21,-21 -21,-23c0,-2 34,-20 44,-15c10,5 29,24 33,28c4,4 10,20 16,5c6,-15 28,-31 -1,-46c-29,-15 -25,-24 -55,-25c-30,-1 -42,-5 -53,-5c-11,0 -46,-2 -52,1c-6,3 -46,16 -46,16z" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="none"/>
  <path id="svg_5" d="m428,180c0,0 -3,52 -4,53c-1,1 -2,27 -2,31c0,4 -8,29 -11,34c-3,5 -15,36 -21,38c-6,2 -77,18 -81,18c-4,0 -68,0 -68,7c0,7 -1,18 8,23c9,5 23,9 45,14c22,5 97,12 111,6c14,-6 44,-20 55,-30c11,-10 28,-28 37,-42c9,-14 14,-15 23,-40c9,-25 16,-109 12,-114c-4,-5 -32,-12 -45,-9c-13,3 -59,11 -59,11z" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="none"/>
 </g>
</svg>
```

So you can either use simple css to show a tooltip or even javascript for more custom tooltip behaviour.

```css
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 125%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="tooltip">Hover over me
  <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. My issue is, how would I enable this for every datapoint of "d" in path? 

For example, a given `d` attribute in path will have a series of values like `m200,114l-114,95l26,97l99,20c0...` - etc.etc. Is it possible to create a tooltip for each single one of them?
I've only managed to create a tooltip for the whole `path` element.

Comment: do your datapoints need to be a single path? I would split it into multiple svg subelements

Comment: Apologies for my ignorance, if I wanted to keep displaying them as a density plot as per above, wouldn't having them a single path be the only way? Or is it possible to split them up?

Answer (score 1):

I had found error in X-Axis, I updated Code and Now it's show correct way.

`d3.scaleLinear().domain([refs.current.dataMin, refs.current.dataMax])`
to
`d3.scaleLinear().domain([0 refs.current.dataMax])`

```js
const xScale = useMemo(() => {
    try {
      const result = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, refs.current.dataMax]).range([ 10 , boundsWidth - 10 ]);
      return result
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error creating xScale:", error);
      return d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 1]).range([boundsWidth - 10 , 10]);
    }
  }, [importedData, width]);
```

[image]